# Run Firefox multiple times from different locations

Tags: firefox, browser

I want to open 10 instances of Firefox (or another browser if not possible) with different proxies in each one of them.
I have downloaded "Firefox Portable" and installed in a two different locations, but I can't open them up at the same time - I have used the command -no-remote-, but it doesn't work when Firefox is located in a different locations.

Is it possible to open Firefox multiple times while they are on different locations? if not, how can I run 10 instances of browser with different proxy on each?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [Profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) to run multiple copies of Firefox with independent settings.

You can start the Profile Manager by invoking Firefox with the `-P` command line argument. You can optionally add a name of an existing profile to skip the Manager and directly open that profile. E.g., `-P MyProfile`.

Using this, you *do not* need multiple copies of the Firefox program itself. One copy (portable or normal) can be started many times with different profiles.